# Highcharts error 14 array remove double quotes

Tags: jquery, arrays, parsing, highcharts, casting

Hello i have an array and need to remove the quotes at flugstunden cause Highcharts can't handle strings but i have no clue how. i have allready used map and and for loop but i fail , anybody an idea how i can solve it? : [highcharts error page](http://www.highcharts.com/errors/14)

[image]

```
vars.jaProChart = pJson.aaData;
console.log(vars.jaProChart);
```

Comment: Need more info - where is your JSON being generated? That's the ideal place to ensure the numeric values are sent as numbers instead of strings. Makes a lot more sense than looping through it again after the fact. If you're stuck having to loop, look at the `parseFloat()` and/or `parseInt()` functions.

Comment: I get the json from an java backend and java get the data from sql in both cases i parse the value as an double , i will try tomorow to parseFloat with an for loop hope it works , thanks for ur advice.

Comment: So, whatever function in your Java is encoding the data as JSON should be able to handle properly encoding them as double. I don't have the knowledge of Java to point out where/how, but that's where I would focus first if I were you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var data = parseFloat(urData.replace(',','.'));
```

Solved :)